# Binding a class to DOM setting Timeout in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, controller

I have an animation working when the class `"fa-counter"` is added to the DOM.

I want that the animation start working after 3 seconds i land in the page. How can i control that in ember?

I have found Ember.run.later an option to use , but i struggle on how to implement it.

The code

Html

```
{{#if isAnimate}}
    <i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw big fa-counter"></i>
{{else}}
    <i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw big"></i>
{{/if}}
```

So if it `isAnimate` the class `fa-counter` makes start the animation

In my controller by default `isAnimate` is `false`

```
var MenuController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isAnimate: false,
    startWatchingAnimation: function(controller){
        var self = this;
        Ember.run.later(function(){
          self.set('isAnimate', true);
        }, 1000);
    },
});
```

I have thought also to access to access the scoped JQuery object with the this.$() method.

Html

```
<i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw big"></i>
```

Controller

```
var MenuController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isAnimate: false,
    startWatchingAnimation: function(controller){
        Ember.run.later(this, function(){
            this.$('.fa').addClass('.fa-counter');
        }, 500);
    },
});
```

No one of the two methods really work, how can i achieve that?

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? Asking because I will answer your question but would prefer not using deprecated syntax or APIs (such as ObjectController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, this is a job for your the view [component] because the view [component] is heavily tied to the state of the DOM. If the element is removed from the DOM, your animation is longer valid. Your `Ember.run.later` instinct is on par with what I would do, but there is a little bit more to it. Here's my example:

```
// app/components/my-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isVisible: false,

  _startTimer: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
    this._visibleTimer = Ember.run.later(this, () => {
      this._visibleTimer = null;
      this.set('isVisible', true);
    }, 3000); 
  }),

  _endTimer: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function() {
    if(this._visibleTimer) {
      Ember.run.cancel(this, this._visibleTimer);
    }
  })
});
```

---

```
// app/templates/components/my-component.js
<i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw big {{if isVisible 'fa-counter'}}"></i>
```

In this case you do have think about it slightly differently. Instead of thinking about it as "I want to animate something", you have to think about it as "I want to be in a state" ... and the transition between those states is an animation. So by default it's invisible, and then after 3 seconds it becomes visible.